# SQLite Query for a character with a prefix and a suffix

Tags: string, sqlite, substring

Okay actually I'm writing a program for parsing Japanese/Chinese text, but I try to map it to an english example. No, I don't want to use it to create password lists :).

Suppose there is a text without spaces (space is not used in most east asian languages) like :

```
helloiamwritingproperenglish!
```

Given is a specific character position in the text like the `r` in proper:

```
helloiamwritingproperenglish!
                ^
```

so the text can be decomposed in `prefix + 'r' + suffix`.

---

Additionally there is a dictionary stored in SQLite containing character combinations (words) like:

```
sqllite>SELECT writingKey from dic_writings;

writingKey
----------
A, Aa, ...
```

---

I want to find all regular words in the dictionary that are containing the selected character 'r' and a (maybe empty) substring of prefix and suffix like:

```
sqllite>FindCandidates('helloiamwritingp','r','operenglish!');
R, Pro, Rope, Prop, Proper
```

A Query to find all words in the input `text` could be:

```
SELECT * FROM dic_writings WHERE (text LIKE ('%'||writingKey||'%'));
```

but this approach is not very fast and I need to filter the words containing the selected 'r' (checking for 'r' is not enough actually). Anybody has an idea? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you please post your CREATE TABLE statements and a few sample INSERTS to clarify your question a bit?